# How to find lowest non-empty dollar-formatted value in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, variables, min

I try to find the lowest non-empty value of a set of values. I use this code, which works, but not for dollar formatted prices of different lengths:

```
$lowestPrice = min($var1 ?: PHP_INT_MAX, $var2 ?: PHP_INT_MAX, $var3 ?: PHP_INT_MAX, $var4 ?: PHP_INT_MAX);
```

If the prices have the same length it works, but if you compare **$20.99**, **$129.00** and **$12.50**, it will say that **$129.00** is the lowest.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Convert it to number first. Before you ask "how" - imagine how you would do that manually first

Comment: can't seem to reproduce, works fine [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2ZYNow)

Comment: @Ghost: same here, but if you change 12.50 to 22.50 it won't work any longer?

Comment: @zerkms: that is possible but then I need to convert the number back to the format to output it. So I hoped remaining the formatting would cut of a step.

Comment: hello @coder check my answer below, should also work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put them inside an array first, then use `natsort()`. Example:

```
$values = array('$1,129.00', '$22.50', '', '$20.99');
$values = array_filter($values);
$temp = $values;
array_walk($temp, function(&$val, $key){
    $val = str_replace(',', '', ltrim($val, '$'));
});
natsort($temp);
$key = key($temp);
$lowestPrice = $values[$key];
echo $lowestPrice;
```

Comment: Edit: I thought it worked, but with values above 1k: $1,200.95 it doesn't.

Comment: @coder okay il make some test cases, will get back to you in a sec

Comment: @coder wow thats some real test case? you sure you're going to have thousand separators? anyway, check my revision

Answer (score 1):

It is most likely that theprices are saved as strings, that's why 129.00 (it starts with a 1) is 'lower' than 29.00 (starting with a 2). You need to convert the prices to doubles:

First you need to use the variables as a list:

```
$array = list($var1, $var2, $var3, ...);
```

Alternatively, if there are lots of `$var<x>`s, then you can use variable variables to create the array:

```
// $var1, $var2, ..., $var13 do exist;
// $var14 does not, so 13 is the highest_var_number.
$highest_var_number = 13;

// Fill the array with the values.
$array = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $highest_var_number; $i++) {
    $array[] = ${"var".$i};
}
```

Then convert all numbers to doubles:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = (double) $array[$key];
}
```

Comment: I pull them out of the DB as seperated variables, how would this look on $var1?